# if conditions do not ignore lines in a text file

Tags: awk

Why the below awk command does not ignore columns which starts with `ChrC` and `ChrM`:

```
awk '{if($1 != "ChrC" || $1 != 'ChrM') print $0}' TAIR10_GFF3_genes-fix1.rm_rubbish_rm_protein_rm_id_rm_index.gff | cut -f1 | sort | uniq
Chr1
Chr2
Chr3
Chr4
Chr5
ChrC
ChrM
##gff-version 3
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why did you use different quotation marks with ```ChrC``` and ```ChrM```?

Comment: Another option is `\r\n` line-ending (if those `'` quotes are a typo).

Comment: may  be hidden chars? try !~/ChrC/ as condition

Comment: or appen ```od```at the end of your pipeline and post output here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since samples are not provided so couldn't test it, could you please try changing your condition inside `awk`. IMHO why it is printing it because its an OR condition so if 1 of the part fails then also it will print line(based on the 
 logic of OR condition of `1 || 0` --> `1`), which will NOT happen in case of `AND` condition.

```
if($1 != "ChrC" && $1 != "ChrM")
```

Comment: Works after changing to `"`

Comment: I believe the question was updated, because there are samples now

Comment: @user977828, I added further explanation on why your attempt didn't work, please check it once too.

Answer (score 1):

Try (using `"`)

```
awk '{if($1 != "ChrC" || $1 != "ChrM") print $0}' TAIR10_GFF3_genes-fix1.rm_rubbish_rm_protein_rm_id_rm_index.gff | cut -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Probably `print $1` would save you the `cut`.

Comment: Works after changing to `&&`. Why it is not working with `||`?